# Use a trait conditionally in PHP

Tags: php, traits

I want to use a trait in a class, only if a condition is satisfied. For example:

```
trait T
{
}
class A
{
    if ($condition) {
        use T;
    }
}
```

I know I can't use `if` directly in class. So, I'm looking for a way to use traits conditionally similar to the above. Is it possible?

Comment: It looks like XY problem. Tell us what is your primordial problem?

Comment: You can create a class with `use T` which extends the class without `use T`. And then in your code where you use the class do an if and instanciate the one or the other class.

Comment: Please don't use condition you just use T then check in these function and use exception through

Comment: @Asif Sounds interesting. Can you provide us an example?

Comment: please look below my answer

Comment: @sectus I want to make 'Timestamps' as a trait and use them in classes only when they are enabled (most probably through a config).

Comment: Timestamps is an integer value. You cannot use them as trait...

Comment: @sectus I mean, to create a trait "Timestamps" that has [created_by] and [modified_by] properties.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create a class with use T which extends the class without use T. And then in your code where you use the class do an if and instantiate the one or the other class.

```
<?php

trait T {
}

class A {
}

class B extends A {
    use T;
}

// In an other part of code
$obj = null;

if($condition) {
    $obj = new B();
} else {
    $obj = new A();
}

/* EOF */
```

Comment: The most nit solution, I'd say.

Answer (score 4):

As long as your condition can be evaluated at the class root, you can do the following:

```
if (<condition here>) {
    class BaseFoo
    {
        use FooTrait;
    }
} else {
    class BaseFoo {
    }
}

class Foo extends BaseFoo
{
    // common properties
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that really solves it at the called site rather than on the caller site or inside the trait. So, that's why i upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

You can outsource your conditional code (like debug-functions) in a trait and do something like that.

```
//your Trait

if($isModeDbg){
    trait Dbg{
        function dbg(mssg){
            debugbarOrSomethingSimilar(mssg);
        }
    }
}else{
    trait Dbg{
        function dbg(mssg){
        }
    }
}

//your class
class Something{
  use Dbg;
}
```

Comment: While this works with PHP7 the Eclipse IDE (Oxygen 3) warns *"Cannot declare type Dbg because the name is already in use"*. Another option is to put the different traits in different files and only `require` the one you want.

Comment: No no, I only ran your program, there was no Dbg declared earlier or elsewhere. The interesting thing is that the IDE complained about your code, but PHP 7.0 did not. Your code is perfectly valid.

Comment: is Dbg reserved in some way by the IDE. DId u tried a different trait-name?

Comment: I just tried your suggestion but that didn't change the mind of the latest version of Eclipse Oxygen 3 + PDT. No worries, the code is still valid and will be executed by PHP 7+ without error.

Answer (score 1):

```
trait T {
function getType() { 
     if($condition){ /*somthing*/ 
          }else{ 
           throw new Exception('some thing.') 
        } }
function getDescription() { /*2*/ }
}
class A {
use T;
/* ... */
}
```

Comment: Okay that's also a possible solution. Depending on what's in the if condition one of us solutions makes more sense.